# How to get only a file form a Github PROTECTED repository

Tags: curl, github, download, wget

I am trying to download an installation script of a project that is in a Github protected repo.

`user` and `repo` below are replaced by the correct info.

I have tried curl:

```
curl -u gabipetrovay -L -o install.sh "https://raw.github.com/user/repo/master/admin/scripts/install.sh"
```

Curl prompts for the password but as soon as I type the first character it goes further and downloads something (a lot of JS probably from Github)

I also tried wget:

```
wget --user=gabipetrovay --ask-password "https://raw.github.com/user/repo/master/admin/scripts/install.sh"
```

With wget I can enter my complete password but then I get a 503 error:

```
Resolving raw.github.com (raw.github.com)... 199.27.73.133
Connecting to raw.github.com (raw.github.com)|199.27.73.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Connection timed out
2013-10-14 10:18:45 ERROR 503: Connection timed out.
```

How can I get the install.sh file? (I am running this from an Ubuntu server 13.04)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I download a single raw file from a private github repo using the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126559/how-can-i-download-a-single-raw-file-from-a-private-github-repo-using-the-comman)

Answer (score 7):

And the official response from the Github guys is:

> Thanks for getting in touch!  For this case, you'll want to use our API to download individual files:
>
> http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents
>
> With this endpoint, you can get a specific file like this:
>
> ```
> curl -u gabipetrovay -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.raw" "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/contents/filename"
> ```
>
> You'll just be prompted for your GitHub account password in this case, or you can also  use an OAuth token as well.  For reference, our API Getting Started Guide has a nice section on authentication:
>
> http://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/#authentication

And this works like a charm!

Thanks Robert@Github

Answer (score 3):

You can use the V3 API to get a raw file like this (you'll need an OAuth token):

`curl -H 'Authorization: token INSERTACCESSTOKENHERE' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -O -L https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/contents/path`

All of this has to go on one line. The `-O` option saves the file in the current directory. You can use `-o filename` to specify a different filename.

To get the OAuth token follow the instructions here:
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use

This allows better automation if you, say, need to do this from a shell script.

I've written this up as a gist as well:
https://gist.github.com/madrobby/9476733

Comment: if you want to retrieve a file stored in a specific tag (say: my_unit_rest) you would specify the curl command as follows (as in a bash script):
`USER="me";
PASSWD="mypasswd";
OUTPUT_FILEPATH="./foo";
OWNER="mycompany";
REPOSITORY="boo";
RESOURCE_PATH="project-x/a/b/c.py";
TAG="my_unit_test";
curl  -u "$USER:$PASSWD" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw' -o $OUTPUT_FILEPATH" -L "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPOSITORY/contents/$RESOURCE_PATH?ref=$TAG";`

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with GitHub with API, so only one solution is working for me for private repos:

`https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/<path/to/file>`

with sending the `login:token` in `CURLOPT_USERPWD`

It returns the array where `download_url` have desired url with token in it which is generated dynamically and differ from your access token (so it's the key to solve it).

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an oauth token as explained there : [Github basic authentication](http://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication)

then you can use the following command, curl get a temporary url so you need to use '-L' in curl to follow the redirection :

```
curl -L -u <your token>:x-oauth-basic https://raw.github.com/user/repo/master/admin/scripts/install.sh
```

You can also use -o "filename" to save it on disk

Comment: I have tried this and this is not working. You get a 503 error (even with redirects)