# Ruby download_file from https drops RuntimeError

Tags: ruby, git, buildpack

I have a file on git https://github.ibm.com/********/buildpack_resource/blob/master/*****.tgz that I want to download (to Win10) with the following code:

```
download_file(dependency['uri'], local_cached_file)
```

I receive `` C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/buildpack-packager-2.3.4/lib/buildpack/packager/package.rb:126:in `download_file': Failed to download file from https://github.com/*******/buildpack_01/blob/master/*****.tgz (RuntimeError) ``

I can't ping the address, but I can ping git.com.
I'm quite new in Ruby. I'm just using this gem, but the error messages looks informative. I still can't understand what goes wrong.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Can you locate the file directly on https://github.ibm.com? Can you download it from there? Notice that the "View Raw" link appends `?raw=true` to URL

Comment: hi @petrpulc I can navigate on github to the file. I can step in it as it is a tgz, so its a zipped folder. I used the url that I copied when I stpped in into the tgz... . Not sure how I can download a file from a git. I can get the link of the .git itself.. and I can download the .git too. It's a private git.

Comment: Can you navigate browser to https://github.ibm.com/********/buildpack_resource/blob/master/*****.tgz?raw=true ? Does this result in download? Or do you need to download the file form ruby script?

Comment: thx @petrpulc! I can copy out this link open in a new browser. I get a github screen where I see my file. And now I also see a download button. When I press it I see the raw.. thing you mentioned: http://raw.githubusercontent.com appears in the windows opern or save popup window...

Comment: Will add an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Download raw from GitHub portal with browser**

If the download itself is satisfactory `?raw=true` to the URL of the browsed file on GitHub portal.

Or follow: [Download single files from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604663/download-single-files-from-github)

**Download file with wget / curl / other script**

Is possible, but authorization needs to be carried out: [How can I download a single raw file from a private github repo using the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126559/how-can-i-download-a-single-raw-file-from-a-private-github-repo-using-the-comman)

**Clone the repository**

Or actually clone the repository. To get only the last revision, switch `--depth=1` may be used.

Comment: trying hard.. but not working yet :( I'm using the answer I found under your link to "Download file with wget/curl/other script. First I try to create some soert of https://api.github.com/repos/.... url

Comment: maybe I need a token set up on github?

Comment: But beware, you need to use URL of your company github.

Comment: Yes, you need a token, but not on github.com, but on github.ibm.com (Maybe ask your IT how to obtain it and use it ;) )