# Get raw data from private repository

Tags: python, http, github

I want to download a zip file from my **private** repository from GitHub. Ths is my link to my **private** GitHub repository

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<NAME>/Folder/master/dataset.zip?token=<TOKEN>
```

Unfortunately I get an `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`, so also in Python. Is there a option to get the raw data from my private GitHub repository ? I want to get access and download it in Python. I used a `Personal access token` for that.

```
# GitHub Access
file_url= ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<NAME>/Folder/master/dataset.zip?token=<TOKEN>")
zipped_file = keras.utils.get_file("dataset", file_url, extract=False)
print(zipped_file)

[OUT] HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

# Normal Access
movielens_data_file_url = ("http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip")
movielens_zipped_file = keras.utils.get_file("ml-latest-small.zip", movielens_data_file_url, extract=False)
```

Comment: This could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126559/how-can-i-download-a-single-raw-file-from-a-private-github-repo-using-the-comman

Answer (score 0):

The URL you use now is.

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<NAME>/Folder/master/dataset.zip?token=<TOKEN>
```

Take the token from the end and reformat your URL as follows:

```
https://<TOKEN>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<NAME>/Folder/master/dataset.zip
```

and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't know if it works, but keras gives me some erros. `Exception: URL fetch failure on https://<TOKEN>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<NAME>/<FOLDER>/master/dataset_zip: None -- [Errno -2] Name or service not known` is it because the URL is wrong or is there another mistake?

Comment: It is this line `zipped_file = keras.utils.get_file("dataset", file_url, extract=False)`

Comment: And unfortunately the link also doesn't work in my browser.

Comment: Can you download the file with curl and the modified URL? See the command at the end of this article: https://dev.to/killdevils/github-download-a-file-from-a-private-repository-in-github-869

Comment: And the <TOKEN> you use is your personal access token, correct?

Comment: Yes I'm using the personal access token :) and now I can't download the file 404.. :(