# Downloading file from a private repo into R

Tags: r, github

I have a zip file containing data in a private Github repo. I am writing some R code, and I wish to download the data into R. When I run the following code I get a HTTP status was '404 Not Found'. This doesn't happen when the repo is bublic, though.

How can I fix the code to be able to download the file? I believe I need to get a access token, but I don't know well how to get that either and add it to the code. If someone could help, I would appreciate a lot. Thanks.

```
# We give the url a name
url <- "https://github.com/aquijanoruiz/disability_benefits_EC/raw/master/ENSANUT_datasets/BDD_ENSANUT_2018_STATA_.zip"
# We create a temporary directory
td <- tempdir()
# We create the placeholder file
tf <- tempfile(tmpdir=td, fileext = ".zip")
# We download the data into the placeholder file
download.file(url,tf)
```

Comment: Any chance making it work?

Comment: Couldn't make it work. Uploaded the file to my google drive, where a token is not needed, just the url. Thanks for asking.

Comment: OK, thank you for the feedback. I have included your workaround in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

From [r 3.6.2 `download.file`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/download.file), you would need at least to add a header, with `Authorization: token xxx` in it, in order to be properly authenticated (thus having the right to read the repository content).
Use a [PAT (Personnal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Adding a [media type](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/media-types) is also recommended, as seen in "[How can I download a single raw file from a private GitHub repo using the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22314262/6309)", but probably not needed in your case, since you are using the `/raw/` URL directly.

I would use [`remote.download`](https://rdrr.io/cran/remotes/man/download.html), which wraps download.file, and allows to easily set an `auth_header`

```
download(".", url, "<yourToken>")
```

---

The [OP Alonso Quijano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13105016/alonso-quijano), however, had to resort to a workaround (from [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70075161/downloading-file-from-a-private-repo-into-r#comment123950779_70075161)):

> I Uploaded the file to my google drive, where a token is not needed, just the url.

---

As noted by [Kai Aragaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3551101/kai-aragaki) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70075161/downloading-file-from-a-private-repo-into-r/70076984#comment127502368_70076984):

> The `download()` function from remotes isn't exported, so you must access it with `remotes:::download()` (note the three colons instead of two)

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell which scopes or permissions should I select just to allow download of the document?

Comment: @AlonsoQuijano A token with scope repo (https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps) should be enough. Assuming you have the right to access that private repository (either because you are the owner, or a registered collaborator to said private repository)

Comment: Thank again. I am trying to use the download function as you suggest. I loaded the `remotes` package, but it doesn't seem to find the function. I used this code:  
library(remotes)
download(path = tf, url = url, auth_token = "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")  
  
I also tried adding a header to the download.file function.

download.file(tf, url, headers = "Authorization: token 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").  
I have left the token for testing. I can eliminate afterward.

Comment: @AlonsoQuijano it should be `dowload.file(path = ...)`

Comment: Hi, `download.file` does not seem to have a `path` argument.

Comment: @AlonsoQuijano I cannot test it at the moment, so all I can see is https://rdrr.io/cran/remotes/man/download.html, which seems to list path as an argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239505/discussion-between-alonso-quijano-and-vonc).

Comment: For `remotes::download` I now get an error: `Error: 'download' is not an exported object from 'namespace:remotes'`

Comment: @MarkNeal The `download()` function from `remotes` isn't exported, so you must access it with `remotes:::download()` (note the three colons instead of two)

Comment: @KaiAragaki interesting, this is my first exposure to the triple colon. Documentation had this to say: It is typically a design mistake to use ::: in your code since the corresponding object has probably been kept internal for a good reason.