# Import data from organization's private repository on GitHub using R

Tags: r, github, import

I want - and desire that others can do the same - to import some data that is in a organization's private repo on GitHub using R. I have permissions on the organization (I'm the owner).

**So my goal is to produce a fixed link that can be used as input inside functions as** `read_delim()`. To do this task I created a fine-grained PAT (Personal Access Token) with access 'to all repositories owned by the organization'. **But I'm not getting to create such a link from any combination of GitHub raw link and the PAT**.

My question: is that possible? Or am I trying unnecessarily?

Comment: What exactly did you try? What as the result? Did you see the URLs used in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126559/how-can-i-download-a-single-raw-file-from-a-private-github-repo-using-the-comman It seems like you should be able to create a URL but that would include your PAT. So anyone with that PAT would be able to download any file from your repos.